# How to use scrolling capability in java in elasticSearch version 8

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticSearch version 8.2.0. I need to use scrolling capability of elasticsearch but I am not able to find how to use it in Java. in older version of elasticSearch this can be achieved by using SearchScrollRequest, but in new version this class is not available.

Answer (score 1):

If [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/scroll-api.html) is needed, e.g. when the [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) can not be used, because of lack of a unique column of the results, one can use something like:

```java
    var builder = RestClient.builder(
        new HttpHost("some_host.com", port, "https"));
    try (var restClient = builder.build()) {
      var transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
      var client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

      var size = 10_000;

      var searchResponse = client.search(s -> s
              .index("some_index")
              .scroll(t -> t.time("10m"))
              .size(size)
              //optional query
              .query(q -> q.match(m -> m.field("field").query("value"))),
          MyPojo.class);
      var scrollId = searchResponse.scrollId();
      var hits = searchResponse.hits();
      // process the hits

      while (hits.hits().size() == size) {
        var scrollResponse = client.scroll(s ->
                s.scrollId(scrollId),
            MyPojo.class);
        hits = scrollResponse.hits();
        // process the hits
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Elastic-search no longer recommend using the scroll API for deep pagination. If you need to preserve the index state while paging through more than 10,000 hits, use the [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results) parameter with a point in time (PIT)

Comment: As per my use-case I am fine with cost associated with the scroll API. so I want to use it

Comment: `search_after` may be not suitable, if there is no unique column of the records, and it can not use `_id` as sorting column, so Scrolling API is the way in this case.